# Django admin urlpatterns problems

Tags: regex, django, django-admin, django-views

I'm trying to complete a Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) and have run into a problem which, I think, is my understanding of regular expressions and the include() function.

My problematic urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

which, leads me (upon browsing to `http://localhost:8000/admin/`) to the detail view of polls.urls  - the code of which is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

I get why it's matching to polls and getting taken through to polls.urls. Any ideas?

Note: when I comment out the `url(r'^polls/, include('polls.urls')),` line I can see the admin page again

Thanks!

Comment: can you remove url from url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')), ? It is some issue with regex matching.

Comment: Afraid not - I do think it's an issue with regex matching but the url is required. I get just don't understand why it isn't matching `r'^admin/'` when the second `includes` is there but is when it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify(/correct myself), the `url` doesn't seem to be required but its removal, while still allowing me to see my polls pages, won't let me see my admin page.

Answer (score 1):

O.K - so I managed to fix this but am not entirely sure how. It was a case of leaving it and working on other problems and when I came back it was fixed! So, things that I changed:

1.) included `{% load url from future %}` to ensure forward compatibility in my templates

2.) changed the form action in detail.html to `<form action="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote/" method="post">` (from `<form action="{% url 'polls.views.vote' poll.id %}" method="post">`

3.) finally, and probably most importantly - sorted my syntax out! In my views.py file I had `Return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls_results', args=(p.id,)))` and not `Return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_results', args=(p.id,)))`

I still don't know which did it but, if anybody is in the same position as me, some combination of those 3 will do it!